# How do I access this environment variable in the windows git bash shell

Tags: windows, environment-variables, git-bash

I am trying to configure my *windows portable git bash shell*.  When I execute `env` I get:

```
ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\WinAnt
PORTABLEAPPS.COMVIDEOS:FORWARDSLASH=H:/Documents/Videos
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
PORTABLEAPPS.COMLOCALEWINNAME=LANG_ENGLISH
PAL:LASTPORTABLEAPPSBASEDIR:DOUBLEBACKSLASH=H:
PAL:DRIVELETTER=H   **** this is the variable I am after  ******
PAL:APPDIR=H:\PortableApps\GitPortable\App
TEMP=/tmp
```

The variable I am trying to reference is `PAL:DRIVELETTER=H`.  I want to use this set my path in my `.bash_profile` script.  This is all on a USB stick and the drive letter will of course change from time to time.

I have tried echoing:

```
$PAL:DRIVELETTER
${PAL:DRIVELETTER}
```

and numerous other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The bash "Definitions"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html) does mention explicitly:

```
name
```

> A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore.
>   Names are used as shell variable and function names.
>   Also referred to as an identifier.

So your variable name PAL:DRIVELETTER is actually invalid.
You need to extract it from the '`env`' output, as [proposed in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/682177/141):

```
pal_driveletter=$(env |grep "^PAL:DRIVELETTER=" | cut -d= -f2-)
```