# /p cmd option is resolved as a drive letter in git-bash

Tags: cygwin, git-bash, conemu

I used to call this command to popup a simple balloon message when gradle build is complete. It had worked fine on cygwin's bash.

```
notifu /p "Gradle build complete" /m "Now you can take a look at the results" /d 0 > /dev/null
```

However, after switching to git's bash, the windows-style command line options such as `/p /m` have become resolved as cygwin drive letters: `p:/ m:/`. Obviously, `notifu` couldn't accept them.

[image]

Could anybody please tell me why it had been perfectly working on cygwin's bash, but not on git-bash now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@astrounaut use like this in **git-bash**:

```
notifu //p "title" //m "message.."
```

Answer (score 0):

I used previously ([in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20292400/6309)) or seen (in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13701495/6309)) the escape character '^' for Cygwin msys bash.

Try a `^` in front of the `/`, in order to convince Cygwin that `/p` isn't a drive path:

```
notifu ^/p "Gradle build complete" ^/m "Now you can take a look at the results" ^/d 0 > /dev/null
```